# Tracking access or edit history for a specific file

Tags: macos

I am using a Macbook Air with High Sierra.
I need to find out which file was uploaded via Chrome on an exam website since I am afraid I upload the wrong one.

Is there any way to see the precise access history for a file. I cannot just look at the "last access" date/time because I touched all the incriminated files several times unfortunately.

What I am looking to find is some kind of log which tells me *all* the times that a file was accessed so I can see if I touched the correct one at upload time. Any suggestions? Thank you!

I checked the system.log and I also checked the audit files but nothing seems helpful.

Comment: Well, after asking this community, the Apple community and the Chrome community I have reached the conclusion that there is no log of multiple accesses to files or of files on local disk accessed by Chrome. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

macOS (and all other OSs that I know of) only record last access and do not log multiple accesses. It is possible that Chrome remembers in some way.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome has a History menu item that gives you a list of files accessed by Chrome along with the date.  The last option of the History menu is an option to show full history.  This may help you find what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to find the list of accessed files? I can only see the history of the pages accessed not the files

Comment: I just tested this and you are right. Except if you are opening a file the word "file" appears after the name of the site,  You can easily click on the link and the file will open.